# angular13 - keycloak cors config is invalid

Tags: angular, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am using keycloak authentication app. I am using angular13 in UI. I am sending the post request for login as follows.

But the cors settings problem returns. On the keycloak side, I configured the cors settings as follows. But I keep getting errors.

```
private apiUrl:string = `${environment.baseUrl}`;

constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

IsAuthentication(username:string, password:string){
  let body = new URLSearchParams();
  body.set("client_id", environment.client_id);
  body.set("grant_type", environment.grant_type);
  body.set("username", username);
  body.set("password", password);

  console.log(body);

  return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${this.apiUrl}/services/auth/openid-connect/token`, body);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/jangaraj/keycloak-cors-issue-debugging - I bet development on the `localhost` is a problem. BTW: direct access grant flow from the Angular frontend doesn't sound like a secure option.

Comment: t mate, I have read this docs before and I have read almost all the docs on stackoverflow. but I couldn't find a solution :(

Comment: That doc warns before running on the localhost explicitly. So why you are doing that????